# Logging Cache Rebuilds for Drupal

Tags: drupal

I would like to know when Drupal clears the cache (or rebuilds it in more recent versions of Drupal).  Does anyone know how I can get Drupal to record an entry in a log, whenever it clears the cache?  At the risk of sounding like a complete idiot, does Drupal use Drush to rebuild the cache when it does it by itself (on schedule)?  Or, is Drush just for the dumb human to use?

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, try using `hook_cache_flush` or `hook_rebuild` in a custom module and check the results.

As far as I know any rebuild/cache clear will go through these hooks.